# PyQt+QGraphicScene+QThread, перемещение элемента по сцене в фоновом потоке

Tags: pyqt

Добрый день. 
Пытаюсь в фоновом потоке перемещать свой объект по сцене, он перемещается, но при перемещении исчезает и не появляется, если при этом тягать другой объект по сцене, то его перемещение видно. При каждом перемещении делаю апдейт сцены, и представления, но не помогает. Если в потоке менять цвет то все нормально работает.

```
class MyGraphicRect2(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
            super().__init__()
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.width = width
            self.height = height
            self.setPos(self.x, self.y)
            self.color = QColor('red')

            # self.setToolTip('Test')

            self.setAcceptDrops(True)
            self.setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)
            self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
            self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
            self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable, True)
            self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)


            s = Shadow()
            b = Blur()
            c = ColorChange()
            self.setGraphicsEffect(s)
            # self.setGraphicsEffect(c)

            # self.setGraphicsEffect(b)

    def setColor(self, color):
            self.color = QColor(color)

    def boundingRect(self):
            return QRectF(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

    def paint(self, painter, options, widget):
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor('black')))
        painter.setBrush(self.color)
        painter.drawRect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)


class MoveThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self,object,scene,view):
        super().__init__()
        self.object=object
        self.scene=scene
        self.view=view
    def run(self):
        for i in range(1,10):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.object.moveBy(30,0)
            print(self.object.pos().x())
            #self.object.update()
            self.view.updateSceneRect(QRectF(0,0,800,800))


        #for color in ['green','white','black','magenta','yellow']:
         #   time.sleep(1)
         #   self.object.setColor(color)
         #   self.object.update()


class MyGraphicScene(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rect=QRectF(0,0,800,800)
        self.Scene=QGraphicsScene(self.rect)
        self.View=QGraphicsView()
        self.View.setCacheMode(QGraphicsView.CacheNone)
        self.sceneConfig()

    def sceneConfig(self):

        self.Scene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor('yellow'),Qt.SolidPattern))
        self.Scene.setFont(QFont('Impact'))

        item=MyGraphicItem(30,30,100,100)
        self.item1=MyGraphicRect2(100,100,100,100)
        self.Scene.addItem(item)
        self.Scene.addItem(self.item1)
        line=QGraphicsLineItem(80,38,84,38)
        self.Scene.addItem(line)

        #Здесь мы будем добавлять итемы

        self.View.setScene(self.Scene)



    def displayUI(self):
        print('Is scene active', self.Scene.isActive())
        self.setCentralWidget(self.View)
        self.th=MoveThread(self.item1,self.Scene,self.View)
        self.th.start()
        self.resize(1000,1000)
        self.show()


app=QApplication(sys.argv)

m=MyGraphicScene()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```